# Im trying to solve a PnP function, unfortunaly there is some error code which I dont understand

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pytorch, camera

Ive printed out the used variables for a better understanding of the function:

```
corners3D = [[-0.03982  -0.03982  -0.03982  -0.03982   0.036049  0.036049  0.036049 0.036049]
             [-0.04071  -0.04071   0.036889  0.036889 -0.04071  -0.04071   0.036889 0.036889]
             [-0.035134  0.056635 -0.035134  0.056635 -0.035134  0.056635 -0.035134 0.056635]
             [ 1.        1.        1.        1.        1.        1.        1.       1.      ]]
corners2D_gt = [[288.31424 208.85425]
                [289.08606 162.22127]
                [244.11584 209.17488]
                [242.46529 162.14928]]
internal_calibration = [[572.4114   0.     325.2611]
                        [  0.     573.5704 242.0489]
                        [  0.       0.       1.    ]]

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (npoints >= 4 && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, 5), ipoints.checkVector(2, 6))) in cv::solvePnP, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\calib3d\src\solvepnp.cpp, line 64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 404, in <module>
    test(epoch, niter)
  File "train.py", line 211, in test
    R_gt, t_gt = pnp(np.array(np.transpose(np.concatenate((np.zeros((3, 1)), corners3D[:3, :]), axis=1)), dtype='float32'),  corners2D_gt, np.array(internal_calibration, dtype='float32'))
  File "C:\python_work\singleshotpose\utils.py", line 97, in pnp
    distCoeffs)
cv2.error: C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\calib3d\src\solvepnp.cpp:64: error: (-215) npoints >= 4 && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, 5), ipoints.checkVector(2, 6)) in function cv::solvePnP
```

and the line of code which gave the error message:

```
R_gt, t_gt = pnp(np.array(np.transpose(np.concatenate((np.zeros((3, 1)), corners3D[:3, :]), axis=1)), dtype='float32'),  corners2D_gt, np.array(internal_calibration, dtype='float32'))
```

also the pnp function defined in this code:

```
def pnp(points_3D, points_2D, cameraMatrix):
    try:
        distCoeffs = pnp.distCoeffs
    except:
        distCoeffs = np.zeros((8, 1), dtype='float32') 

    assert points_2D.shape[0] == points_2D.shape[0], 'points 3D and points 2D must have same number of vertices'

    _, R_exp, t = cv2.solvePnP(points_3D,
                              np.ascontiguousarray(points_2D[:,:2]).reshape((-1,1,2)),
                              cameraMatrix,
                              distCoeffs)                            

    R, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(R_exp)
    return R, t
```